# Agregate in Tableau Software?

Tags: tableau

I have a Data Source (90000 rows) that represents invoice lines like :

```
year | month | invoice number | customer name | total invoice | article number | qty | total line  
2018 | januar | 001 | toto | 100 | 1234 | 2 | 20  
2018 | januar | 001 | toto | 100 | 4567 | 4 | 80  
2018 | januar | 002 | titi | 120 | 1234 | 6 | 60  
2018 | januar | 002 | titi | 120 | 4567 | 3 | 60
```

I would do a graph with the revenue per year and per month, but when I try Tableau Software sum the total invoice and the turnover is huge.
How do I explain that I want only once the total amount of the invoice by invoice number ?
Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Level of Detail calculation to 'fix' the invoice value to each invoice.

Example:
{fixed [Invoice Number]:max([Total Invoice])}

Then use this calculation on your axis to build the view.